# write dataframe with multiline header

Tags: r

I am trying to write a dataframe with some header information that I have stored in a separate object. Anyone know how to do this?

Everytime I try, the dataframe is written in one column or without header information. I'm doing some data cleaning and need to save out the updated dataframes with the same header information attached.

Thanks for any help!!

```
cars.tsv
=====
Dataset: mtcars

Date: 18 OCT 2020

mpg cyl disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs  am  gear    carb
21  6   160 110 3.9 2.62    16.46   0   1   4   4
21  6   160 110 3.9 2.875   17.02   0   1   4   4
=====
head <- readr::read_lines("cars.tsv", n_max = 4)
df <- readr::read_tsv("cars.tsv", skip = 4)
readr::write_lines(c(head, df), "out_c.tsv")
readr::write_lines(list(head, df), "out_list.tsv")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function will do what you want if you supply it with a data frame and a file path:

```r
write_special <- function(df, filepath) {
  string <- c(paste("Dataset:", deparse(substitute(df)), "\n"),
              paste("Date:", date(), "\n"))
              
  writeLines(string, filepath)
  suppressWarnings(write.table(df, filepath, append = TRUE, sep = "\t"))
}
```

So for example, if I do:

```
write_special(mtcars, "mtcars.txt")
```

Then "mtcars.txt" looks like this:

```
Dataset: mtcars 

Date: Sun Oct 18 20:19:13 2020 

"mpg"   "cyl"   "disp"  "hp"    "drat"  "wt"    "qsec"  "vs"    "am"    "gear"  "carb"
"Mazda RX4" 21  6   160 110 3.9 2.62    16.46   0   1   4   4
"Mazda RX4 Wag" 21  6   160 110 3.9 2.875   17.02   0   1   4   4
"Datsun 710"    22.8    4   108 93  3.85    2.32    18.61   1   1   4   1
"Hornet 4 Drive"    21.4    6   258 110 3.08    3.215   19.44   1   0   3   1
"Hornet Sportabout" 18.7    8   360 175 3.15    3.44    17.02   0   0   3   2
"Valiant"   18.1    6   225 105 2.76    3.46    20.22   1   0   3   1
"Duster 360"    14.3    8   360 245 3.21    3.57    15.84   0   0   3   4
"Merc 240D" 24.4    4   146.7   62  3.69    3.19    20  1   0   4   2
"Merc 230"  22.8    4   140.8   95  3.92    3.15    22.9    1   0   4   2
"Merc 280"  19.2    6   167.6   123 3.92    3.44    18.3    1   0   4   4
"Merc 280C" 17.8    6   167.6   123 3.92    3.44    18.9    1   0   4   4
"Merc 450SE"    16.4    8   275.8   180 3.07    4.07    17.4    0   0   3   3
"Merc 450SL"    17.3    8   275.8   180 3.07    3.73    17.6    0   0   3   3
"Merc 450SLC"   15.2    8   275.8   180 3.07    3.78    18  0   0   3   3
"Cadillac Fleetwood"    10.4    8   472 205 2.93    5.25    17.98   0   0   3   4
"Lincoln Continental"   10.4    8   460 215 3   5.424   17.82   0   0   3   4
"Chrysler Imperial" 14.7    8   440 230 3.23    5.345   17.42   0   0   3   4
"Fiat 128"  32.4    4   78.7    66  4.08    2.2 19.47   1   1   4   1
"Honda Civic"   30.4    4   75.7    52  4.93    1.615   18.52   1   1   4   2
"Toyota Corolla"    33.9    4   71.1    65  4.22    1.835   19.9    1   1   4   1
"Toyota Corona" 21.5    4   120.1   97  3.7 2.465   20.01   1   0   3   1
"Dodge Challenger"  15.5    8   318 150 2.76    3.52    16.87   0   0   3   2
"AMC Javelin"   15.2    8   304 150 3.15    3.435   17.3    0   0   3   2
"Camaro Z28"    13.3    8   350 245 3.73    3.84    15.41   0   0   3   4
"Pontiac Firebird"  19.2    8   400 175 3.08    3.845   17.05   0   0   3   2
"Fiat X1-9" 27.3    4   79  66  4.08    1.935   18.9    1   1   4   1
"Porsche 914-2" 26  4   120.3   91  4.43    2.14    16.7    0   1   5   2
"Lotus Europa"  30.4    4   95.1    113 3.77    1.513   16.9    1   1   5   2
"Ford Pantera L"    15.8    8   351 264 4.22    3.17    14.5    0   1   5   4
"Ferrari Dino"  19.7    6   145 175 3.62    2.77    15.5    0   1   5   6
"Maserati Bora" 15  8   301 335 3.54    3.57    14.6    0   1   5   8
"Volvo 142E"    21.4    4   121 109 4.11    2.78    18.6    1   1   4   2
```

Note that I have not called the file "mtcars.tsv", for the simple reason that because of the extra lines at the top, this is now  *not* a tsv file. If you attempt to read it as one, you will not get your data frame back. You would need another function to read your bespoke file type. Something like:

```r
read_special <- function(filepath) {
  df <- read.table(filepath, skip = 4, header = TRUE)
  fileinfo <- readLines(filepath, n = 4)[c(1, 3)]
  attr(df, "Dataset") <- trimws(strsplit(fileinfo[1], ":")[[1]][2])
  attr(df, "Date") <- trimws(strsplit(fileinfo[2], ":")[[1]][2])
  df
}
```

Which will return the data frame with the extra info "attached" as attributes